# shared web hosting with Git

Tags: git, github, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I know that if I want to use Git to update my web application online but not FTP then I need to buy a new vps or dedicated server but that is out of question since the projects that I work are always new projects and dont have that budget to buy servers. I wanted to know if there is any other solution like web hosting with git support (shared web hosting)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site looks promising, they are offering web hosting with pre-configured git and up to 5 developers: http://www.githoster.com

Comment: looks like straight to the point web hosting.. I am going to consider this

Answer (score 2):

[Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) is one option. They have a free plan that may be good enough for you.

Comment: I am def going to try this out thnx

Answer (score 2):

since TooCool's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24942095/8075150) is outdated use rinetech.com, they provide git and npm and ruby support too on top of basic features every PHP hosting company provides

Answer (score 1):

You can try nixhero.com they are providing [shared web hosting with git](https://www.nixhero.com) support. You will have full ssh access .

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to know if there is any other solution like web hosting with git support (shared web hosting)?

Yes there is. Approx 50% of the major web hosting companies support Git on at least one of their shared hosting plans. [This table](https://b2evolution.net/web-hosting/cheap-plans/comparison-matrix) will show you in detail which plans support Git and which not (Look at the "Git:" line near the bottom of the table)